# Adding a progressbar inside searchview android

Tags: android, searchview, android-progressbar, appcompatactivity

This is below code I am using in my activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(com.c2info.eDawa.R.layout.hll_layout);
    AppController.logite("Activity", "HllActivity");
    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(com.c2info.eDawa.R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.app_launcher);
}

  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(com.c2info.eDawa.R.menu.menu_hll, menu);
    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(com.c2info.eDawa.R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            if (searchView != null)
                searchView.clearFocus();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (newText.length() > 2) {
                getSearchData(newText);                     // this is the service
            }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

In on preExecute i am using

```
this.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(Boolean.TRUE);
```

In on postexecute i am using

```
this.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(Boolean.FALSE);
```

But progressbar is not showing can anyone help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know it's an old question, but do you remember how you solved that problem?